# SharedPreferences getLong() -> java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long. How to fix?

Tags: android, exception, sharedpreferences, long-integer

So there is a method `getLong()` of `SharedPreferences`. There is no way to declare `<long-array>` in `strings.xml`. So in which case we do use geLong()?

`strings.xml`

```
<string-array name="intervals">
    <item>Never</item>
    <item>Minute</item>
    <item>Fifteen</item>
    <item>Half hour</item>
    <item>An hour</item>
    <item>Half day</item>
    <item>Day</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="intervalValue">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>60000</item>
    <item>900000</item>
    <item>1800000</item>
    <item>3600000</item>
    <item>86400000</item>
</string-array>
```

`Preferences.xml`

```
<ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/intervals"
    android:entryValues="@array/intervalValue"
    android:key="interval"
    android:summary="@string/summaryUpdaterInterval"
    android:title="@string/titleUpdaterInterval" >
```

code:

```
public long getInterval()
{
    return prefs.getLong("interval", INTERVAL_NEVER);
}
```

Causes:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return Long.valueOf(prefs.getString("interval", INTERVAL_NEVER));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
public long getInterval()
{
    return Long.valueOf(prefs.getString("interval", INTERVAL_NEVER));
}
```

or that:

```
public long getInterval()
{
    long value = INTERVAL_NEVER;
    try
    {
        value = Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("interval", "" + INTERVAL_NEVER));
    } catch (Exeption e) { }
    return value;
}
```

additionally, if you don't want to declare `INTERVAL_NEVER` as `String`,
replace

```
prefs.getString("interval", INTERVAL_NEVER));
```

with

```
prefs.getString("interval", "" + INTERVAL_NEVER));
```